# How do you unmarshal part of a byte array with a single json.Unmarshal?

Tags: go

The query response I get is always a byte array which can be unmarshaled into an array `Q` of some type and I only want to unmarshal the first element in the query response into an object of unknown type (`interface{}`), so this is what I have and it works.

```
res = Query(query)
data := struct {
    Q []json.RawMessage `json:"q"`
}{}
json.Unmarshal(res.Json, &data)
json.Unmarshal(data.Q[0], &object)
```

The issue is that first I unmarshal res into an array of `json.RawMessage`, then I can unmarshal the first element into `object`. Having to unmarshal, then unmarshal again seems redundant. Is there a more performant solution where I can just unmarshal once?

Comment: can elements of `data.Q` have different types?

Comment: Short: No. Long: Yes, write your own unmarshaler.

Comment: @GauravDhiman Yes. `data.Q` is an array of whatever type `object` is

Comment: "Having to unmarshal, then unmarshal again seems redundant." -- It's not. You're doing two different things, so two steps are necessary. Only seek to optimize this if you determine, through actual benchmarks in actual production, that your performance is suffering. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Decode to this struct:

```
data := struct {
    Q [1]interface{} `json:"q"`
}{
    [1]interface{}{&object},
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(res.Json, &data); err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

The decoder will decode one element of the array to the value pointed to by object.